# Do we have $\|f\|_\infty\leq |f(0)|+\|f'\|_\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

Do we have that for any $C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ function $f$ this: $\|f\|_\infty\leq |f(0)|+\|f'\|_\infty$?

Answer (score 7):

Let $x\in [0,1]$, the MVT theorem implies that $f(x)-f(0)=f'(c_x)x, c_x\in (0,x)$ this implies that $|f(x)|\leq |f(0)|+|f'(c_x)|$ and $\|f\|_{\infty}\leq |f(0)|+\|f'\|_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

*Proof.* Let $x\in[0,1]$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$\int_0^xf'(x)\;dx=f(x)-f(0)$$
and thus
$$|f(x)|\leq |f(0)|+\int_0^x|f'(t)|\;dt\leq |f(0)|+\|f'\|_{\infty}\int_0^11\;ds=|f(0)|+\|f'\|_{\infty}$$
Taking the supremum with respect to $x$, we get the desired inequality.